# return in shortcode wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code for displaying a shortcode.

```
<?php

function recent_posts_function() {


    $mypost = array( 'post_type' => 'gallery_pictures', );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $mypost );
    ?>

<div id="boxhover">

    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>

    <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>

    <!--Fade-->
    <?php $ddd = '<div class="mosaic-block fade">
        <a href="'. $image[0] . '" data-fancybox-group="gallery" target="_blank" class="mosaic-overlay preview fancybox" title="' . the_title . '">
            <div class="details">
                <h4>' . the_title() . '</h4>
                <p>' . the_content_rss('', TRUE, '', 30) . '</p>
                <br/>
                <div class="btt">VIEW</div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <div class="mosaic-backdrop"><img src="' . $image[0] . '"     alt="gallery thumbnail" /></div>
    </div>';

   endwhile; ?>

</div>
<?php


return $ddd;
} 

function register_shortcodes(){
add_shortcode('gallery', 'recent_posts_function');
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes');
```

as you can see from the above codes, the 'return $ddd' should return all the output from the loops that the 'while' process done but its display only one.

Im currently looking for a solution and would love to hear any suggestion, recommendations and ideas on how to do it. Thank in advance.

Comment: You might want to redirect your question to the WordPress StackExchange site: [WordPress Answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a [dot] before your = [equal] on the loop while.
This will cause each loop add content current with the previous.

```
<?php function recent_posts_function() { 
        $ddd = ''; //First declare the string var ?>
...
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>

  <?php $ddd .= '<div class="mosaic-block fade">'; // Put a [dot] before sign symbol ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
...
return $ddd;
...
<? php } ?>
```

Comment: this was my solution actually, thanks for the help, really appreciated!